# Leanback launcher for 7.1.2

Tags: android, apk, launcher, android-tv, leanback

I recently got the Bqeel AX9 MAX, an android tv box, and I'd like to install the Leanback launcher instead of the basic one. The issue is that my box run with Android tv 7.1.2 and I searched all over internet without finding the good apk which support the API 25. I also tried to extract it from the Gapps but the package seems to be "corrupt".. Does anyone have any idea where to find it ? or any solution ?
I'm also interested if you know about any Netflix release for it.